# How do I ensure fieldset elements all conform to the same height in larger viewport sizes despite differing content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple `fieldset` elements within a single `form` element oriented using Bootstrap 3.0.0 such that I have three distinct columns. I am okay with the way the form displays in smaller viewport sizes. However, I would like the `fieldset`s to always align with one another as the viewport size changes. I am not tied to using Bootstrap 3.0.0 specifically. I am simply using it here as an example. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/raigsingh/428uZ/8/) is my jsfiddle. Once I started using Bootstrap `panel` within `fieldset` elements, I felt I was heading down the wrong path.

What is the correct way to achieve the alignment with Bootstrap 3.x+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem last week, but I thought I would update the answer. `fieldset` elements will not really "align" with one another where the height and widths conform to one another because when content changes, the `fieldset` size will change as well. A better way to achieve this effect though would be to remove the borders around each `fieldset` and contain everything within a Bootstrap 'container-fluid' `div`. Other 'container-fluid' `div` elements can then be stacked so that *their* containing `fieldset` elements line up.

Remove the border around each fieldset

```
fieldset.fs-border {
    border: 1px groove #ddd;
    ...
}
```

Remove the references to `panel` classes (not sure why I added this in the first place. Using `panel` is more useful if I want to wrap all `fieldset` elements within a collapsable `panel`, for example.):

```
    <fieldset class="col-sm-4 panel panel-primary fs-border">
        <legend class="panel-heading legend-border">Primary Contact</legend>
```

Use `display:table`, remove the border, and specify this in a class referenced by the containing `div`.

```
.wide-container {
    display: table;
    background-color:#d7e0e2;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

All `fieldset` elements would then be contained within that `div` if you wanted to stack "groups" of fieldset elements. Their borders will all appear to line up uniformly:

```
<div id="fieldsetGroup2" class="wide-container container-fluid">
    <fieldset id="fieldset1" ...>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fieldset2" ...>
    </fieldset>
    ...
</div>
<div id="fieldsetGroup2" class="wide-container container-fluid">
    <fieldset id="fieldset3" ...>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fieldset4" ...>
    </fieldset>
    ...
</div>
```

where `container-fluid` will make the content span the entire area contained within the `div`.